# Logging on THE Chrome Console: 010 prints 8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I entered 10 on the Chrome Console and it printed 10. However when I entered 010, it prints 8. I was doing some bit manipulation experiment when I cam across this. Any explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a zero before the number causes the number to be interpreted in octal. This means that `010` is `1 * 8 + 0 * 1` aka `8`. It is similar to writing `0x10` for a hex value which would result in `16` when out putted in base 10 (the default). There is no prefix for binary so you would have to use something like `parseInt('10', 2)` resulting in a value of `2`.

Comment: That sounds bout right. How do you represent binaries and hexadecimals then?